# Github - Traffic - Strange "Git clones" statistics

Tags: git, github

I have a Github repo with some confusing Git clone statistics.  As you can see below, the repository does not have a large number of visitors or Stars, and yet shows a relatively large number of clones on a Sep. 29.

The Github [help page for traffic](https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-traffic-to-a-repository/) is not very helpful, but I assumed that a "clone" statistic would count each individual clone command issued.  It does not seem possible that 3 cloners cloned this repo almost 400 times in one day.

What else could this statistic represent?

[image: Github Traffic page screenshot]

Comment: I think someone (not me) may have downvoted your question because it seems unlikely that anyone on Stack Overflow would have an answer to this unless they got it directly from a GitHub support email. Moreover the nature of the graph makes it seem like a transient GitHub systems issue, and not actually reflective of the repo's real analytics. Might I recommend sending this question to GitHub support, and then coming back to share the authoritative answer here?

Comment: By the way, one redditor has a guess at an answer for you: `both git-pull and git-clone actually call git-fetch under the hood, in addition to doing the work relevant to their commands. [...] i doubt github tries to differentiate fetches that are part of a git-clone from ones that are simply appending an existing repo. (i'm not even sure that would be possible, haven't given it much thought)` https://www.reddit.com/r/github/comments/3a4bv0/the_github_stats_on_clonesunique_cloners_seems/csd6vnm/

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for finding that thread.  Good to know I'm not missing something obvious here - I'll ask Github support to see if my own actions might be racking up that clone count.

Comment: hey @sean, glad you posted it here, I too think something is different here, I created a new repo last night at 23:50, and it shows 6 unique clones for yesterday itself how come in 10 mins I got https://github.com/FindTheDifficult/zip-node/graphs/traffic

Comment: @sunil-lulla, it certainly does look like some type of bot activity is fairly common across github. Perhaps someone is simply doing public code statistical analysis, and sometimes pulls the same repo multiple times.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since this was not expected behavior, I contacted Github Support and got this answer:

> That number is accurate, and represents someone running `git clone`.
>   However, I did a little digging, and those clones came from only 4
>   unique users.
>
> One possibility is that it's just a script gone wrong.

So it wasn't "normal" behavior, but not a Github bug.  The answer to my question is that this statistic does represent the `git clone` command.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to share the support response with everyone.

Comment: Does it indicates that the graph is against all the `git clone` command and not combining `git clone` and `git pull`?

Comment: Github Support just mentioned that it was referring to the `git clone` command, but did not specifically clarify that it excluded other ways that command is used. I also don't know if that statistic has changed in the past ~2 years.